# Get multiple response from API in flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a user registration API written in node but the API gives me three types of responses

1. If the registration is successful then the below JSON is the response

```
     {
      "message": "success",
      "ccontent": {
        "_id": "5ef7c4c414529241205fb590",
        "email": "sam@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$05$4TFPKJ83O7jSPhjtIIDj1ud5pjhS9GY.I0C.IFlBDyUFsd6i4E3Ci",
        "__v": 0
      }
    }
```

2. If the user already exists it just gives me a string response

   already-exists
3. If error occurred

   error-occurred

I have a future function to get the response from the API

```
class RegistrationService {
  String registrationUrl = 'http://192.168.1.6:8080/api/user/create';

  Future userRegistration(email, password) async {
    Response response = await post(registrationUrl,
        body: {"email": email, "password": password});
    var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return RegistrationResponse.fromJson(result);
  }
}
```

This works only when the user registration is a success but when it fails error occurs telling unhandled exception 'already-exists' or 'error-occurred'

How can I get all types of responses from the API in this future function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could throw an exception in case response is `already-exists` or `error-occurred`

```
class RegistrationService {
  String registrationUrl = 'http://192.168.1.6:8080/api/user/create';

  Future<Map<String, dynamic> userRegistration(email, password) async {
    Response response = await post(registrationUrl,
        body: {"email": email, "password": password});
    
    if (userAlreadyExist(response.body)) {
       // already-exists response
        throws UserAlreadyExistException();
    }
    else if (errorOccurred(response.body)) {
        // error occurred response
        throws SomeOtherException();
    }

    var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return RegistrationResponse.fromJson(result);
  }
}
```

You would need to implement methods `userAlreadyExist` and `errorOccurred` to detect this situation and decide what's the best exception type for every case. You would also need to cath the exception when you call `userRegistration` so you can react properly.